# How can I make a global variable with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to pass function `a_href = $(this).attr('href');` value to global `a_href`, make `a_href="home"`

```
var a_href; 

    $('sth a').on('click', function(e){
        a_href = $(this).attr('href');

          console.log(a_href);  
         //output is "home"

        e.preventDefault();
    }

console.log(a_href);  
//Output is undefined
```

Comment: only problem is if the `var a_href` is inside a dom ready handler... the variable declaration mush be in the global space or use `window.a_href = $(this).attr('href')`

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Your code looks fine except the possibility that if the variable declaration is inside a dom read handler then it will not be a global variable... it will be a closure variable

```
jQuery(function(){
    //here it is a closure variable
    var a_href;
    $('sth a').on('click', function(e){
        a_href = $(this).attr('href');

          console.log(a_href);  
         //output is "home"

        e.preventDefault();
    }
})
```

To make the variable global, one solution is to declare the variable in global scope

```
var a_href;
jQuery(function(){
    $('sth a').on('click', function(e){
        a_href = $(this).attr('href');

          console.log(a_href);  
         //output is "home"

        e.preventDefault();
    }
})
```

another is to set the variable as a property of the window object

```
window.a_href = $(this).attr('href')
```

**Why console printing undefined**

You are getting the output as `undefined` because even though the variable is declared, you have not initialized it with a value, the value of the variable is set only after the `a` element is clicked till that time the variable will have the value `undefined`. If you are not declaring the variable it will throw a [ReferenceError](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ReferenceError)

Comment: Thanks a lot, will tick it :-)

Answer (score 10):

set the variable on window:

```
window.a_href = a_href;
```

Answer (score 4):

You can avoid declaration of global variables by adding them directly to the global object:

```
(function(global) {

  ...

  global.varName = someValue;

  ...

}(this));
```

A disadvantage of this method is that *global.varName* won't exist until that specific line of code is executed, but that can be easily worked around.

You might also consider an application architecture where such globals are held in a closure common to all functions that need them, or as properties of a suitably accessible data storage object.