# Calculate time spent on website not single page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to calculate total time spent on my website not single page in jQuery.

How can i do that? Please share your views.

I can get time spent on single page via handling jQuery unload event but it reset on new page load.

Comment: Store the value somewhere and modify it with each page.  Local storage, a cookie, server-side, etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to measure a time spent on a page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4667068/how-to-measure-a-time-spent-on-a-page)

Comment: define a global variable check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18995647/jquery-make-global-variable
and then in each document access the variable on the ready state.
$(document).ready(function(){ // use your own way of handling the time});

Comment: To save re-inventing the wheel, use Google analytics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When user enter on any page, you have to know if he navigate between pages or enter on your website. This can be done by look at the last `lastLeave` data in the local storage (you have to set it when user leave a page). You can do something like that:

```
window.onload = function onload() {
  const now = new Date();
  const lastLeave = localStorage.getItem('lastLeave');
  if (!lastLeave || now - lastLeave >= MAXTIME_BETWEEN_PAGE) {
    localStorage.setItem('lastEnter', now);
  }
}

window.onunload = function onunload() {
  localStorage.setItem('lastLeave', new Date());
}

function getTimeSpend() {
  return new Date() - localStorage.getItem('lastEnter');
}
```